How to install varnish version 7.1.1 on mac M1
I need to install Varnish version 7.3 to working with Adobe Commerce ver. 2.4.6-p3 on localhost Mac. As per the Adobe doc the suitable version is 7.3.
When i run the command
brew install varnish

It will install the latest varnish version of 7.5 which is not compatible with my magento version.
I tried to manually download the version from varnish official website i am getting an error

adler32.c:189:15: error: a function definition without a prototype is deprecated in all versions of C and is not supported in C2x [-Werror,-Wdeprecated-non-prototype]


uLong ZEXPORT adler32(adler, buf, len)


1 error generated. make[3]: *** [libvgz_la-adler32.lo] Error 1
make2: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 make1: *** [all-recursive]
Error 1 make: *** [all] Error 2

I am trying to install and setup on Mac M1, Is there anyway to
1 - downgrade the version
2 - Install the required version using command line
Please give me your suggestion or any help highly appreciated.

To install an older version, sometimes the command brew install <package_name@version> will work.
In your case you should try the below command :

brew install varnish@7.3.0

Reference Link :
https://itssiva.medium.com/how-to-install-a-specific-version-of-haproxy-or-any-brew-package-a87561119e63

thanks for the answer, i used doccer container to install varnish on mac

congratulations :)
